# Update: I cant enqueue any core scripts. Masonry wont load with enqueue handle, Wordpress 3.6.

Tags: masonry

I'm trying to load masonry but I'm having no luck, I've managed to load it manually but then I realised it was included in the wordpress core, so I thought oh that's handy.

I have it enqueue' (I really hate that word) like this:

```
function lart_front_end_scripts() {
            if (is_admin()) return;
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery', '1.10.2' );
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry', array('jquery'));
        }//End add_scripts

add_action('wp_print_scripts', array(&$this,'lart_front_end_scripts'));
```

Other jquery is loaded like normal, but I keep getting "masonry has no method" in the console and it's clearly not being loaded because of its absence under network - scripts console.

Help much appreciated.

**Edit: I've updated my code to use enqueue_script instead of print_script.**

```
function masonry() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry');
}//End add_scripts

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'masonry'));
```

Still no dice.

Comment: In your [duplicate Q](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119993/my-theme-doesnt-have-access-to-core-scripts-like-masonry-or-underscore), you say this works on TwentyEleven but not in your theme. What theme is this and what does it has in its `functions.php` that would produce this?

Comment: @brasofilo Yes I have wp_head(); in my header

Comment: We're not seeing the full context of your code. Are you actually inside of a class? Where is other jquery being "loaded like normal"? Inside this callback, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I made Underscore and Masonry a Dependency of another script and then it worked.

I stopped trying to enqueue add action core scripts and just set it as a dependency for the script that needed it.

Now, I'm not entirely sure if that is how it's supposed to work, I thought you still had to enqueue add action the script before you could set it as a dependency, the advantage of core scripts was that you just didn't have to register it.

So without enqueue add action'

`wp_enqueue_script('homeJS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/home.js', array('jquery','underscore','jquery-masonry') );`

Now all of of my required scripts work.

To clarify, only homeJS is being enqueue' with:

`function enqueue_script(){
if(is_admin()) return;
wp_enqueue_script()......
}`

Jquery, Masonry and other *core* scripts have not been enqueued this way.

Comment: Could you explain the solution in more detail and perhaps post the code your used?

Comment: @s_ha_dum updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Masonry is bundled with and already registered by WordPress.

All you have to do, is to enqueue it:

```
function lart_front_end_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry');
} // function lart_front_end_scripts
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'lart_front_end_scripts'));
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question and it's still not working :/

Comment: Yes to all the above, the function is in a class, jquery is loaded and all of my other scripts I've enqueued the same way are working. I also had trouble with with enqueue' underscore.js and ended up using a cdn instead.

Comment: Also it's wp_enqueue_scripts with the "s" at the end right? as in add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')

Comment: The action hook is named [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) and the function is named [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: Ah yes, thought so, but I got nothing yet. I'll try enqueue' some other core wordpress stuff.

Answer (score 0):

> wp_print_scripts should not be used to enqueue styles or scripts on the front page. Use wp_enqueue_scripts instead.

Just use [wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myScripts');
function myScripts (){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', '1.10.2' );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry', array('jquery'));
}
```